# Location of Clojures do form

Tags: clojure

I am trying to locate where do form is defined looking in clojure.core it does not exist. I would like to figure out how do statement is translated to Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look to [Compiler.java, line 4662](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/612fba9159c6986cf875f97e086337f24a5ea3d8/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L4662) to see how **do** is handled:

Answer (score 7):

The `do` form is a [special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms) and as such isn't implemented in clojure. Look through the [`clojure.lang.Compiler`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) class to see how the clojure compiler treats it.